# Using fundamental theorem of calculus in Sturm-Liouville orthogonality proof

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, orthogonality, sturm-liouville

> **Theorem:**
>
> The eigenfunctions of the Sturm Liouville BVP
>
> $$\int_0^a \sin \left( \frac{n \pi x}{a} \right) \sin \left( \frac{m \pi x}{a} \right) \ dx = 0$$ when $m \not= n$.
>
> satisfy the integral relationship
>
> $$\int^b_a r(x) \phi_n(x) \phi_m(x) \ dx = 0$$
>
> If $m \not= n$
>
> where $\phi_1, \phi_2, \phi_3, \dots$ are eigenfunctions, and $\phi_n$ corresponds to the eigenvalues $\lambda_n$.
>
> Hence the set of functions for the Sturm-Liouville problem orthogonal on the interval of interest, with regards to the weight function $r(x)$.
>
> **Proof:**
>
> Since $\phi_n$ and $\phi_m$ are eigenfunctions, they must satisfy the ODE
>
> $$\frac{d}{dx} \left( p(x) \frac{d \phi_n}{dx} \right) + q(x) \phi_n = - \lambda r(x) \phi_n \ \ \ (1)$$
>
> $$\frac{d}{dx} \left( p(x) \frac{d \phi_m}{dx} \right) + q(x) \phi_m = - \lambda r(x) \phi_m \ \ \ (2)$$
>
> Multiply (1) by $\phi_m$ and (2) by $\phi_n$ and subtract:
>
> $$\phi_m \frac{d}{dx} \left( p(x) \frac{d \phi_n}{dx} \right) - \phi_n \frac{d}{dx} (p(x) \frac{d \phi_m}{dx} = (\lambda_m - \lambda_n)r(x) \phi_n \phi_m$$
>
> The left-hand side can be expressed as
>
> $$\frac{d}{dx} \left( p(x) \left( \phi_m \frac{d \phi_n}{dx} - \phi_n \frac{d \phi_m}{dx} \right) \right)$$
>
> Therefore, the equation becomes
>
> $$\frac{d}{dx} \left( p(x) \left( \phi_m \frac{d \phi_n}{dx} - \phi_n \frac{d \phi_m}{dx} \right) \right) = (\lambda_m - \lambda_n)r(x) \phi_n \phi_m$$
>
> Integrate both sides with respect to $x$ from $a$ to $b$:
>
> $$\left[ p(x) \left( \phi_m \frac{d \phi_n}{dx} - \phi_n \frac{d \phi_m}{dx} \right) \right]^b_a = (\lambda_m - \lambda_n) \int^b_a r(x) \phi_n \phi_m \ dx$$

What I'm trying to figure out is how integrating both sides with respect to $x$ from $a$ to $b$ gets us

$\left[ p(x) \left( \phi_m \frac{d \phi_n}{dx} - \phi_n \frac{d \phi_m}{dx} \right) \right]^b_a = (\lambda_m - \lambda_n) \int^b_a r(x) \phi_n \phi_m \ dx$

As I understand it, this is an application of the fundamental theorem of calculus part 2 (called part 2 in my textbook):

> If $f$ is continuous over $[a, b]$ and $F$ is any antiderivative of $f$ on $[a, b]$, then
>
> $$\int_a^b f(x) \ dx = F(b) - F(a)$$

Can someone please demonstrate how this was done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:
$$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{df}{dx}dx=f(b)-f(a)$$

It is the fundamental theorem of calculus. The $\lambda$'s are constant and therefore come out of the integral.

Comment: I have a set of notes on integration: http://hyperkahler.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/integration.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Your functions $f_n(x)=\sin(n\pi x/a)$ are solutions of
$$
               -\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f=\lambda f,\;\;\; 0 \le x \le a, \\
                     f(0)=f(a)=0.
$$
So you have a weight function $r(x)\equiv 1$, coefficient $p\equiv 1$, and potential $q\equiv 0$. The eigenvalues are $\lambda_n=n^2\pi^2/a^2$. Therefore, the general theory gives
$$
      \int_{0}^{a}f_n(x)f_m(x)dx = 0,\;\; n \ne m,\;\; n,m=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$